# nodejs express to serve static content on POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to serve static content on POST requests but can't find how to do it.

Express has a .static method but it only seems to handle get requests. Not sure how I am going to get it to serve posts.

I have created json files that need to be served on a post so they can simulate endpoints without actually having the server code installed.

Tried something like this

```
var express = require('express');
var ws = express();
ws.use(express.static('../static'));
ws.get('*', four_oh_four);
ws.post(express.static('../static'));
```

Not sure how to get this to work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need that? Usually the content is retrieved with a get method

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Thank you for your reply; json post requests are handled by server side code, this code is not available for graphic designers, testers and front end developers. The only thing they have is the json file representing the json that would have been returned by the server if the server code, mongo db and a lot of other things were installed.

Comment: you could try 
ws.post('*', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'postme'));
});

Answer (score 1):

Got it working the following way:

```
ws.post('*.json',dummyData );
function dummyData(paramRequest, paramResponse){
    var path = '../static'+paramRequest.url;
    fs.readFile(
        path,
        function (err, contents) {
            if (err) {
                send_failure(res, err);
                return;
            }
       contents = contents.toString('utf8');
            paramResponse.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
            paramResponse.end(contents);
        }
    );
}
```